# In pandas adding a time offset to a subset of the dataframe has no effect

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, slice

I noticed a strange behaviour of the pandas package, that leads to an unexpected failure to add time offsets in some cases.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['2022-01-24', '2022-02-24', '2022-03-24'], 
                   'value': [10, 20, 30]})
```

I can successfully add a time offset to it using this syntax:

```
df.set_index(['time'], inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = df.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)
```

But there is a fail, when I want to add the offset only to a subset of the dataframe, e.g. only to dates after `2022-02-25`, see below:

```
df.set_index(['time'], inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df[df.index>pd.to_datetime('2022-02-25')].index = df[df.index>pd.to_datetime('2022-02-25')].index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)
```

The second code slip leads to no change in the column `time` of `df`. Why nothing changes when I perform the adding only to a slice? And how do I successfully do it? Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try set the whole index with new values (not just only part of it, if the index is sorted):

```py
mask = df.index > pd.to_datetime("2022-02-25")

df.index = (
    *df[~mask].index,
    *(df[mask].index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)),
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            value
2022-01-24     10
2022-02-24     20
2122-03-24     30
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! But can you explain in your answer as well why my code snippet didn't work? And what are you doing differently to make it work?

Comment: @NeStack I guess you're setting only copy of values of original index, so the new values aren't propagated to the whole dataframe.